# Plotting using Pandas and datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with just two columns, Date, and ClosingPrice. I am trying to plot them using df.plot() but keep getting this error:

> ValueError: view limit minimum -36785.37852 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

I have found documentation about this from matplotlib but that says how to make sure that the format is datetime. Here is code that I have to make sure the format is datetime and also printing the data type for each column before attempting to plot.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

print(df['ClosingPrice'].dtypes)
print(df['Date'].dtypes)
```

The output for these print statements are:

> float64
>   datetime64[ns]

I am not sure what the problem is since I am verifying the data type before plotting. Here is also what the first few rows of the data set look like:

`Date  ClosingPrice
0    2013-09-10       64.7010
1    2013-09-11       61.1784
2    2013-09-12       61.8298
3    2013-09-13       60.8108
4    2013-09-16       58.8776
5    2013-09-17       59.5577
6    2013-09-18       60.7821
7    2013-09-19       61.7788`

 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an issue plotting this.  Can you post the line of code that causes the error?

Comment: It is occurring on the line that has df.plot(). Nothing else is on the line. I can provide more of the code if you would like?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT 2** after seeing more people ending up here. To be clear for new people to python, you should first import pandas for the codes bellow to work:

```
import pandas as pd
```

**EDIT 1: (short quick answer)**

If³ you don't want to drop your original index (this makes sense after reading the original and long answer bellow) you could:

```
df[['Date','ClosingPrice']].plot('Date', figsize=(15,8))
```

**Original and long answer:**

Try setting your index as your Datetime column first:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Just to be sure, try setting the index dtype (edit: this probably wont be needed as you did it previously):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

And then plot it

```
df.plot()
```

If this solves the issue it's because when you use the `.plot()` from DataFrame object, the X axis will automatically be the DataFrame's index.

If² your DataFrame had a Datetimeindex and 2 other columns (say `['Currency','pct_change_1']`) and you wanted to plot just one of them (maybe `pct_change_1`) you could:

```
# single [ ] transforms the column into series, double [[ ]] into DataFrame
df[['pct_change_1']].plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

Where `figsize=(15,8)` you're setting the size of the plot `(width, height)`.

Comment: So I added the first line but it appears to be removing the data I want to say. I print the dataframe after the line you recommended and it says None. Along with this error:     df.plot()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: I am not sure if pandas changed something but I changed your first line to df = df.set_index('Date'). And it worked and plotted fine. Thank you for the help. I just tried your last edit and that also worked.

Comment: Ohh it's because since I'm declaring the `df =` the `inplace=True` is not needed. It would if you just typed `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`. Either that or because we're running different python versions (i'm at thr latest).

Comment: Your last edit worked for me df[['Date','ClosingPrice']].plot('Date', figsize=(15,8))

Comment: Good to know, probably it's because you're saying which column must be the X axis at ".plot()" so it's not considering the DF's index.

Comment: Your last edit should be the first, that's what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try, its the "EDIT 1" at the top now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
  my_dict = {'Date':['2013-09-10', '2013-09-11', '2013-09-12', '2013-09-13', '2013-09-16', '2013-09-17', '2013-09-18',
     '2013-09-19'], 'ClosingPrice': [ 64.7010, 61.1784, 61.8298, 60.8108, 58.8776, 59.5577, 60.7821, 61.7788]}

  df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
  df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
  df.plot()
```

Comment: Hello, this won't work because you didn't set the index inplace (`df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`) or replaced the df to the new df with new set_index (`df = df.set_index('Date')`)